# Accessing str inside JSON

Tags: json, api, twitter

I am trying to solve an issue with the json file that I get from the twitterAPI api.request.

I am trying to extract the links to the media inside of each tweet with this piece of code:

```
for item in api.request(TWITTER_ENDPOINT, TWITTER_PARAMS):
if 'entities' in item:
        if 'media' in item['entities']:
            page = item['text']
            link = item['entities']['media']['media_url']

elif 'message' in item:
    print('ERROR %s: %s\n' % (item['code'], item['message']))
```

The format of the field in the json file is a str according to the API documentation, and I can print it if I use this:

```
    urls = [user['media_url'] for user in item['entities']['media']]
    print(type(urls[0]))
```

But the problem is that then I have it stored in a list. What would I need to do to create a variable "link" of type string?

The format of the JSON is this:

```
"entities": {
  "hashtags": [],
  "symbols": [],
  "user_mentions": [],
  "urls": [],
  "media": [
    {
      "id": 707667182633619500,
      "id_str": "707667182633619456",
      "indices": [
        23,
        46
      ],
      "media_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/media/CdIjjaAUEAA7-VU.jpg",
```

I am a beginner in Python, and I would really appreciate a bit of help with this!

Comment: I'm not exactly clear what you are looking for. Maybe it is as simple as this `link = urls[0]`. This defines a variable called "link" that will contain a string if `urls[0]` exists. You will want to test if "urls" does indeed contain at least one element. Note: "link" will be typed a string only if `urls[0]` is a string. This typing happens dynamically.